# Spring Cloud Stream notify Producer that message is consumed

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have several spring boot applications that uses spring cloud stream for messaging. I use rabbitmq as binder.

I am trying to send a message from one microservice to another. In Producer side, before sending message to consumer microservice , I am changing status of one entity to RUNNING. In case consumer service  is down, I need to revert changes to my entity.  I am trying to find a way to acknowledge producer side, if message is consumed by consumer side or not . I wonder if we can use rabbitmq binder consumer acknowledgeMode =AUTO property. Or any other solution. Could you give me a hint about problem ?

Comment: I don't mean to say RTFM, but was wondering if you saw this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/4.1/rabbit/rabbit_overview/publisher-confirms.html#page-title. Please take a look and if you still have questions feel free to post a followup.

Comment: Sorry Oleg. I did not check this new development version